# DHL messed up completely, then were very rude with me. Is it libel/defamation if I publish it on the web?

Tags: united-states, defamation, libel, slander

Some background first,

A few months ago I was living abroad and then came back to my hometown. When coming back, I sent myself a package which was full of all my daughter's first drawings from kindergarten. As you can imagine, while commercial value is basically zero, this has big emotional value to me.

To keep things short, my package never arrived and they basically lost it. But they've never told me they did, they kept telling me to "wait", "wait a few weeks", etc... and suddenly they now tell me that the package doesn't exist and even that I never hired them for this (wtf!).

I tried escalating the issue with them but I am basically being ignored. I already explored the possibility of suing but I cannot get much from it since commercial value is pretty much zero and I don't want to spend money/time on this as it won't my package magically appear, which is what I want.

I have plenty of evidence (emails, phone recordings, etc...) of what they did, I have an audio recording of one of their employees being extremely rude with me on the phone.

Now, I am a very talented developer and I wouldn't mind spending a weekend or two putting all of this together and publishing into a website + some SEO so that, at least, a lot of people find out the kind of stuff they will pull on you, if they wanted to.

It is my understanding that, as long as what I publish is truthful, it shouldn't constitute defamation, but I may be wrong, hence why I'd rather ask first.

Also, I'm in the US if that's relevant. Thanks.

Comment: If it is defamation, you just committed it.

Comment: Sad but happens

Comment: Be careful. You may just come over as rather entitled and petulant.

Comment: A separate question is whether it was legal for you to record your conversation with the DHL employee.  Did they consent to being recorded?  Some states require the consent of both parties.  (And the question of whether to apply the law of your state, or the state where the employee is located, is complicated.)  If your recording was illegal, then posting it or disclosing that you made it may cause you bigger troubles than a defamation suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is my understanding that, as long as what I publish is truthful, it shouldn't constitute defamation

That is correct. Under US defamation law, *truth* is an absolute defense in claims of defamation.

Publishing your evidence will tend to deter the company from suing you for defamation insofar as the company's vexatious intent would be more obvious.